# Django 1.5 rc1 admin user creation form with custom fields

Tags: django, django-admin

I could not find a way of showing the customized user's custom required fields on the 'add new user page' of admin.

I have created a custom user that extends AbstractUser and added three required custom fields. I did not create custom UserManager because i am extending from AbstractUser not AbstractBaseUser.

For admin side:
1. I have created a custom UserCreationForm by extending it. Inside the meta class i added those new three custom fields

But i can not see the custom fields on the admin side. Am i doing smt wrong?

Here is the code for admin side:

```
class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('customField1', 'customField2', 'customField3',)

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': [('username', 'password', 'customField1', 'customField2', 'customField3'),]}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                   'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
        )



admin.site.register( CustomUser, MyUserAdmin)
```

Comment: SOLUTION  ---   Adding  'add_fieldsets' to extended UserAdmin class makes the fields appear.   add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'customField1', 'customField2', 'customField3', )}
        ),

Comment: Hey @ratata Can you post your solution as an answer that we can resolve it as answered!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLUTION --- Adding 'add_fieldsets' to extended UserAdmin class makes the fields appear.

```
add_fieldsets = ( (None, { 'classes': ('wide',), 'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'customField1', 'customField2', 'customField3', )} ),
```